# $(f\circ C(0))´=0$, Quadratic form on the unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Theorem: Let $A$ be a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Let $f(X)=\langle AX,X\rangle$
>
> for $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $v$ be on the unit sphere, such that $f(v)\geqslant f(X)$ for all $X$ on this sphere. Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Proof. Let $w$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is perpendicular to $v$. It is easily shown that there exists a differentiable curve

$C:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^n$

lying on the sphere, defined on an open interval containing $0$, such that $C(0)=v$ and such that the tangent vector $C$ at $0$ is $w$, namely $C´(0)=w$.
[For instance, the curve $C(t)=(\cos t)v+(\sin t)w$ is such a curve.] Since $f(v)=f(C(0))$ is a maximum for $f$ on $S$, it is a maximum for $f\circ C$ on the interval $(a,b)$, and hence $(f\circ C)´(0)=0$. But by using the rule for differentiating a product,

$(f\circ C)´(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\langle AC(t),C(t)\rangle=2\langle AC(t),C´(t)\rangle$.

Hence $0=(f\circ C)´(0)=2\langle AC(0),C´(0)\rangle=2\langle Av,w\rangle$.

Hence $Av$ is perpendicular to every vector $w$ which is perpendicular to $v$. and it follows that $Av$ lies in the space generated by $v$, in other words, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. This proves our theorem. ***Linear Algebra,Serge Lang***

**Questions:**

How can the author state that $(f\circ C(0))´=0$ ? How does he know it?

Answer (score 1):

> Since $f(v)=f(C(0))$ is a maximum for $f$ on $S$, it is a maximum for
>   $f\circ C$ on the interval $(a,b)$, and hence $(f\circ C)´(0)=0$.

What's the first thing you learned in first year calculus about the derivative at a maximum of a function?

---

Edit: After taking the conversation to chat, it resolved that the confusion was over exactly what quantity was being maximized. The original poster was thinking "where the length of my vector $C(t)$ is longest" (which maximizes $\|C(t)\|$ ), while the proof meant "where $(f \circ C)(t)$ is maximized".

Comment: I know that the derivative $(f\circ C(0))´=0$ because $t=0$ determines the maximum. However what I want to know  why  is $t=0$. What does he mean with the $(a,b)$ interval?

Comment: $(a,b)$ must be the angle, and the author uses only one variable for the angle $t$. As I change the angle the line moves inside the sphere but all points in which the line touches the sphere inwards is a maximum ,right? So $t=0$ would be arbitrary.

Comment: I think Lang writes this way here because it's a common way of thinking when you're doing differential geometry. To take a derivative at a point you need functions that are defined on an interval around that point (not just at the point), but the interval can be arbitrarily small. So $(a,b)$ could be $(-1/2, 1/2)$, or $(-1/1000, 1/1000)$. And he uses $t$ as the variable that runs from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: You're right that as $t$ changes the vector (or point, you can think of it either way) stays on the unit sphere. But I don't understand what you mean by "touches the sphere inwards". Because of the way that $C(t)$ is defined, $t=0$ is the specific value of the parameter when the curve $C$ passes through $v$. My mental picture is of the hand of a clock passing through $12$.

Comment: I guess it makes sense because $v$ would be the maximum and it is defined to be on the unit sphere. And if we take the equation $C(t)=(\cos t)v+(\sin t)w$, $v=C(0)$.

Comment: As I picture it, I guess the touching of the sphere does not depend on $t$, but on the length of the vector that was previously defined.

Comment: $C$ stays on the unit sphere because of two facts 1) $v$ and $w$ are orthonormal vectors, and 2) $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$.

Comment: Exactly it stays on the sphere but the tip of the vector is always touching the sphere once $\|v\|=1,\|w\|=1$, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65665/discussion-between-user275313-and-pedro-gomes).