# Proving $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ using a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ex doubt

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> 2. More generally, let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Let $S$ be the surface defined by the equation $\phi(X)=0$. Assume that for each $P$ in $S$, $\nabla\phi(P)\neq0$, and assume that $S$ is closed and bounded. Let $A$ be a real symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix and let $f(X)=\langle AX,X\rangle$. Let $v$ be a point of $S$ such that $f(v)\geqslant f(X)$ for all $X$ on $S$. Show that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$. ***Linear Algebra, Serge Lang***.

I thought of proof of the theorem in the following link [$(f\circ C(0))´=0$, Quadratic form on the unit sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430477/f-circ-c0%c2%b4-0-quadratic-form-on-the-unit-sphere)

So I defined vector $v$ to be perpendicular to $w$. I had to come up with an example of a plane where $C(0)=v$ and $C´(0)=w$ such as in the link proof. I wrote the following equation $z=\cos(t)v+\sin(t)v$. The derivation follows the proof on the link.

**Questions:**

**1)** Can I define a plane like $z=\cos(t)v+\sin(t)v$? Is this plane still valid for the proof?

**2)** How can I define a closed and bounded surface such as it is stated on the question?

**3)** I would be thankful if anyone could provide me a proof.

Thanks in advance